# What options are available for securely storing refresh tokens for DevOps REST APIs in an azure function app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication for user through a powershell function app in Azure.  Reading through the [devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts), it specifically recommends persisting the refresh token on the app server:

> Securely persist the refresh_token so your app doesn't need to prompt the user to authorize again. Access tokens expire relatively quickly and shouldn't be persisted.

What is the best practice for storing the refresh token? I can think of a number of ways but I'm afraid that I will do something naïve.

Comment: You can store the refere token in Azure key vault as secret.

Answer (score 0):

Storing access tokens poses a greater security risk, since an access token in and of itself can access resources. The recommended approach is not to store access tokens, but get the access tokens as needed. Securely store only the refresh tokens, with as much rigor as if they were access tokens. If necessary, you can [revoke refresh tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-revocation) if they become compromised.

This solution uses Azure Key Vault, Azure Functions, and Azure DevOps to securely update and store OBO (OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of (OBO) flow) refresh tokens.

More details you could refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/secrets/secure-refresh-tokens

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?